# How can I make MIAB automatically copy all mail sent via SMTP into the sent folder of the sender's account?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I run Mail-In-A-Box on my mail server and one of my clients is using a specialized application to send messages via SMTP from their account on my server. When they used their own Gmail account to send via SMTP all the mail sent would automatically be copied into their Sent folder. I know that this is not something an SMTP server is supposed to do and that Gmail has just engineered something to do this extra step for the end user, but I would like to find a way to do the same thing on my MIAB server.

Does anyone know of a way to configure MIAB to do this additional step automatically, or even any way to write some kind of cron job or server side script that could read the SMTP log and generate the sent messages in the Sent fold of that user if the message is not already there.

My client is not able to use any other application for sending these messages and the application they are using cannot be modified to make an additional IMAP connection to create this Sent message. It can only function in the limited way in which it was designed to send out the mail via SMTP.

EDIT: I have tried Paul's suggestion but am having trouble getting it to work. First I created a file called /etc/postfix/bcc_maps and in it I put the Senders Email Account followed by the Email Address to be BCC'd with any mail sent by this user, like this:
sendersaddress@theirdomainonmyserver.com bccaddress@toreceiveallsent.com

Yes, the first address is actually the email account on my mail server for this user, and the second address is, in reality, one of my real email addresses (to see if I get the email that was sent from the first address to another party, and no, I did not get the email).

I did also add the following line to the /etc/postfix/main.cf file which did not already have any settings for sender_bcc_maps in it:
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc_maps

I also restarted the postfix service before testing the SMTP send through that user's email account. The desired recipient does still get the email but my BCC address does not get anything, even in the spam folder.

Anyone know have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: welcome. Please read carefully [ask] and update the question, in the current point of view there is no configuration, no other information on the technology point to support the understanding.

Comment: This is a Postfix question that requires you to utilize `sender_bcc_maps`.

Comment: Hi Paul, This suggestion might work for me if I can get it to work but I must be doing something wrong. Can you please elaborate on your answer and maybe post and example?